Distinct divisors with identical remainders.
When $f(x)$ is divided by $g(x)$ the remainder obtained is $R$.
And when $f(x)$ is divided by $h(x)$ the remainder obtained is $R$.
Can we prove that $g(x)$ is a factor of the quotient when $f(x)$ is divided $h(x)$?
Now we have $$f(x)=L_1(x) \times g(x) +R$$
$$f(x)=L_2(x) \times h(x) +R$$
then we can get $$L_1(x) \times g(x) = L_2(x) \times h(x) $$
from here, how can I proceed?

This doesn't appear to be true. Set $f(x)=x^3$, $g(x)=h(x)=x^2$. Are there any other conditions on the polynomials?

Counter example.
$$x^4 - 16 = (x^2 - 4) \times (x^2 + 4)$$
and
$$x^4 - 16 = (x - 2) \times (x^3 + 2x^2 + 4x + 8).$$
So, let $~h(x) = (x^2 - 4), ~g(x) = (x - 2).~$
Then $~g(x)~$ is not a factor of $~(x^2 + 4).~$
Perhaps the posted question failed to mention a constraint, such as $~h(x)~$ and $~g(x)~$ have no common polynomial factors. Adding that additional constraint, while I suspect that the assertion would then be true, my knowledge of field theory is too weak to be certain of my suspicion.
